# After making a route for sitemap using 'sitemap' module at the backend, what to do next so that it is discoverable at the frontend?

Tags: express, npm, next.js, sitemap

This is the sitemap route I created to dynamically generate a sitemap. Now what to do next so that I can see sitema.xml full of links

sitemap.js

```
const { SitemapStream, streamToPromise } = require ('sitemap');
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Job = require ('../models/Job');
const PrivateJob =require ('../models/PrivateJob');




let sitemap;

router.get('/sitemap.xml',async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const list= Job.find().select('slug');
        const listPvt= PrivateJob.find().select('slug');



        const jobs = list.map( ({ slug }) => `/jobs/${slug}`);
        const privateJobs = listPvt.map( ({ slug }) => `/privateJobs/${slug}`);

        const smStream = new SitemapStream({ hostname: 'http://localhost:3000/' })
        const pipeline = smStream.pipe(createGzip());

        jobs.forEach(function(item1) {
            // Update as required
            smStream.write({ url: item1, changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8})
        });

        privateJobs.forEach(function(item2) {
            // Update as required
            smStream.write({ url: item2, changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.6})
        });

        streamToPromise(pipeline).then(sm => sitemap = sm)
        
        smStream.end()

        // Show errors and response
        pipeline.pipe(res).on('error', (e) => {throw e})

        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(e)
        res.status(500).end()
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

What to do next so that it can be discoverable at the frontend as I am using next.js at the frontend

Answer (score 0):

Static assets are served through `public` directory in any nextjs app. `sitemap.xml` is also a static asset so you can place it in the public folder and search engines can access it using: `<YOUR_DOMAIN>/sitemap.xml`.

More on [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Nextjs is not going to create sitemap.xml automatically. Maybe you can write a `prebuild` script to generate sitemaps after building your project. You can try [nextjs-sitemap-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-sitemap-generator) for this purpose.

Comment: I created this at the backend and run both backend and frontend server but no XML file automatically created in the front end public folder. Hence 404 error found on localhost:3000/sitemap.xml.

Comment: Its not going to create sitemap.xml automatically. Maybe you can write a `prebuild` script to generate sitemaps after building your project. You can try [nextjs-sitemap-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-sitemap-generator) for this purpose.